# Why is there a lag in videos on React Native Expo app?

Tags: performance, react-native, video, expo, avplayer

I am building a video-based app on Expo / React Native, and there is sometimes and sometimes not a lag when the videos are playing.

When there isn't a lag, tapping the screen leads to the next video instantly. When there is a lag, tapping the screen leads to the next video after a few seconds.

I also have a progress bar that indicates the percentage completed of the video (similar to Instagram stories). When there isn't a lag, the progress bar completes right when the video completes. When there is a lag, the progress bar is usually only 75% complete when the video has completed.

Here is a link to my app: https://expo.io/@vaibhavverma9/realtalk

I am trying to figure out why my app goes so slowly sometimes and goes smoothly other times.

I use animated bars for the progress bars, if that helps at all.

```
  function ProgressBarsContainer () {

    const width = progressBarWidth(); 
    return (
        <View style={homeStyles.progressBarContainer}>
          {initAnimatedBars(width)}
        </View>
    )
  }

  function initAnimatedBars(width) {
    const animatedBars = []; 

    for (let i = 0; i < currentUserVideoCount; i++){
      if(i < videoIndex){
        animatedBars.push(
          <ProgressBar
             progress={1}
             width={width}
             key={i}

             color="#734f96"
             unfilledColor="#E6E6FA"
             borderColor="#000"
             borderRadius={1}
             height={3}
            />
        )
      } else if (i == videoIndex) {
        animatedBars.push(
          <ProgressBar
            key={i}
            progress={currentProgress}
             width={width}
             color="#734f96"
             unfilledColor="#E6E6FA"
             borderColor="#000"
             borderRadius={1}
             height={3}

            />
        )
      } else {
        animatedBars.push(
          <ProgressBar
             progress={0}
             width={width}
             key={i}
             color="#734f96"
             unfilledColor="#E6E6FA"
             borderColor="#000"
             borderRadius={1}
             height={3}
            />
        )
      }
    }
    return animatedBars;
  }
```

I also render multiple videos at the same time for performance.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'; 
import { Video, Audio } from 'expo-av';   
import { View, Animated } from 'react-native';

export default function MultipleVideos(props) {

    const renderedGroup = props.limit; 

    let initialIndex;
    let indexLimit;  
    if (props.first) {
        const renderedIndex = Math.round(props.userIndex / renderedGroup); 
        initialIndex = renderedIndex * renderedGroup;
        indexLimit = renderedIndex * renderedGroup + renderedGroup / 2; 
    } else {
        const renderedIndex = Math.floor(props.userIndex / renderedGroup); 
        initialIndex = renderedIndex * renderedGroup + renderedGroup / 2; 
        indexLimit = renderedIndex * renderedGroup + renderedGroup; 
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
            playsInSilentModeIOS: true
        }); 
    }, []);

    const playingData = { 
        isMuted: false, 
        shouldPlay: props.shouldPlay, 
        playbackObject: props.playbackObject, 
        _onPlaybackStatusUpdate: props._onPlaybackStatusUpdate, 
        display: "flex"
    }

    const nonplayingData = {
        isMuted: true, 
        shouldPlay: false, 
        playbackObject: null, 
        _onPlaybackStatusUpdate: null, 
        display: "none"
    }

    const renderedVideos = [];

    if(props.videoData) {

        for(let i = initialIndex; i < indexLimit; i++){
            const user = props.videoData.users[i];

            if(user){
                for (let j = 0; j < user.userVideos.length; j++){
                    const muxPlaybackId = user.userVideos[j].muxPlaybackId; 
                    const muxPlaybackUrl = 'https://stream.mux.com/' + muxPlaybackId + '.m3u8';

                    if(props.userIndex == i && props.videoIndex == j){
                        renderedVideos.push(
                            <PlayingVideo
                                key={muxPlaybackId}
                                playbackObject={playingData.playbackObject}
                                source={muxPlaybackUrl}
                                isMuted={playingData.isMuted}
                                shouldPlay={playingData.shouldPlay}
                                _onPlaybackStatusUpdate={playingData._onPlaybackStatusUpdate}
                                display={playingData.display}
                            />
                        )            
                   } 
                    else {
                        renderedVideos.push(
                            <PlayingVideo
                                key={muxPlaybackId}
                                playbackObject={nonplayingData.playbackObject}
                                source={muxPlaybackUrl}
                                isMuted={nonplayingData.isMuted}
                                shouldPlay={nonplayingData.shouldPlay}
                                _onPlaybackStatusUpdate={nonplayingData._onPlaybackStatusUpdate}
                                display={nonplayingData.display}
                            />
                        )    
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return(
            <View>
                {renderedVideos}
            </View>
        )    
    } else {
        return null; 
    }
}

function PlayingVideo({playbackObject, source, isMuted, shouldPlay, _onPlaybackStatusUpdate, display}){
    return(
        <Video
            ref={playbackObject}
            source={{uri: source}}
            // posterSource={{ uri: posterSource}}
            // posterStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', display: display, flex: 1 }}
            rate={1.0}
            volume={1.0}
            isMuted={isMuted}
            resizeMode="cover"
            usePoster={true}
            shouldPlay={shouldPlay}
            onPlaybackStatusUpdate={_onPlaybackStatusUpdate}
            progressUpdateIntervalMillis={50}
            isLooping
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', display: display}}
            >
        </Video>
    )
}
```

Please let me know if there is something that comes to mind that might help improve performance. Thanks :)